# Error "not mutually convertible in Unicode program" when adding line to table

Tags: abap

I'm trying to add data from a internal table to a custom one.

```
 DATA: BEGIN OF TMP_CTRYGRP_T OCCURS 1000,
  CTYGR TYPE /SAPSLL/CTYGR,
  TEXT1 TYPE /SAPSLL/TEXT60,
  END OF TMP_CTRYGRP_T.

SELECT ctygr, text1 FROM /SAPSLL/CTYGPT INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_countryGroupsTable)


LOOP AT lt_countryGroupsTable ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_countryGroups>).
  APPEND <ls_countryGroups> TO TMP_CTRYGRP_T.
ENDLOOP.
```

Then I want to add the line in a custom Table Type ZZ_T_TAB

[image: Custom Table Type Structure]

So I've tried to create a field-symbol of this table, creating an internal table from it, but none of the solutions I've tried was permitting me to add lines in that Custom table (even if the one in the program had the lines).

The problem I mainly encountered was:

> are not mutually convertible in a Unicode program.

So my questions are:

- Why does that error happen? Googling it didn't provide me an understandable answer
- For the moment I'm using an internal table limited to 1000 rows. But I don't really know by advance the number of lines the search could provide. Is there any way to improve that?
- How to add lines from any solution to my ZZ_T_TAB then? And afterwards how could I add other fields in the same table, for the rows already existing?

As some of you maybe understood, I'm quite a rookie in ABAP.
So if there's any useful link to understand all of that I would be happy if you can share it with me.

Comment: What a "custom table" means? DB table? Is this your full code?

Comment: @szako i meant a DB table yeah, not only a Table Type, but one that stores data for real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why don't you directly select into the table?
2. Don't use `OCCURS` as it is declared obsolete and already forbidden in classes.
3. Declare your own structure as type and mark your custom internal table as `TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF struct_type`. This way, there will be no upper bounds

   ```
   TYPES:
   BEGIN OF struct_type,
       CTYGR TYPE /SAPSLL/CTYGR,
       TEXT1 TYPE /SAPSLL/TEXT60,
   END OF struct_type.

   DATA tmp_ctrygrp_t TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF struct_type WITH EMPTY KEY.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> Why does that error happen? Googling it didn't provide me an
>   understandable answer

You cannot use APPEND with non-identical structures. You have to "convert" it before. Look up for the command MOVE-CORRESPODING in ABAP help (F1 on command in editor).

> For the moment I'm using an internal table limited to 1000 rows. But I
>   don't really know by advance the number of lines the search could
>   provide. Is there any way to improve that?

Do not use OCCURS extension it is deprecated (as lausek wrote), old syntax.

> How then to add lines from any solution to my ZZ_T_TAB ? And
>   afterwards how could I add other fields in the same table, for the
>   rows already existing?

You can modify a DB table various ways.:

1, Use UPDATE statement to directly update a field value.
2, Use MODIFY statement to modify field values from a (for example) pre-selected 
structure.

Look up the UPDATE and MODIFY command in ABAP help, there are really helpful code examples.